# sklearn pipeline with multiple inputs/outputs

Tags: scikit-learn, pytorch

How can I build a sklearn pipeline to do the following?

What I have:

```
A, B = getAB(X_train)
X_train = transform(X_train)
model(A, B, X_train)
```

What I want:

```
pipe = Pipeline([
(‘ab’, getAB),
(‘tranf’, transform),
(‘net’, net)
]
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Please help!

Comment: It's not clear what `A` and `B` are supposed to represent. And what is `model` supposed to be? The instantiation of some estimator, or the fitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is doable by writing a custom transformer that has a fit/transform function. This can be your class:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

def getABTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self): # no *args or **kargs
        pass

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self # nothing else to do

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return getAB(X)
```

Then you can create your `ColumnTransformer` as following:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

clm_pipe = ColumnTransformer([
(‘ab’, getABTransformer, np.arange(0, len(X_train)),  # list of columns indices
(‘tranf’, transform, np.arange(0, len(X_train))),  # list of columns indices
]
```

and a final pipeline with the model:

```
pipe = Pipeline([
(‘clm_pipe’, clm_pipe),
(‘net’, net)
]
```

You can read more about [ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html)