# Build sklearn Pipeline with multiple inputs?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to work my way through [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/matching-questions-answers/problem) HackerRank challenge, where you are given three sets of input data:

1. A paragraph of text (`x_paragraph`)
2. A list of (5) questions (`x_questions`)
3. A list of (5) answers to the questions in 2), but in a random order (`x_answers`)

The task is, given the paragraph of text, match the questions to the answers.

The approach I am trying to follow is first to extract features from the paragraph

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
    ('svd', TruncatedSVD(n_components=100))
])

pipeline.fit(x_paragraph)
```

Use this fitted pipeline to transform the questions and (unsorted) answers, and then find a measure of their similarity

```
xt_questions = pipeline.transform(x_questions)
xt_answers = pipeline.transform(x_answers)

similarity = cosine_similarity(xt_questions, xt_answers)
```

Finally, report the prediction as the most similar answer for each question

```
y_pred = [x_answers[np.argmax(similarities[i])] for i in range(len(x_answers))]
```

We are also provided with the correct answers (`y`) which we can use for training / validation.

My question is whether it is possible (and if so, how) to incorporate the additional input parameters (i.e. `x_questions` and `x_answers`) into the `Pipeline` so I can more easily evaluate the process and tune the parameters as necessary (i.e. incorporate `GridSearchCV` or such and make use of the true `y`)

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58028064/sklearn-pipeline-with-multiple-inputs-outputs) answer and have a vague feeling this should be possible with some combination of custom transformers, `ColumnTransformer` and / or `FeatureUnion` but I just can't quite seem to find the right approach whenever I've tried writing some code. Is there a viable recipe I can follow?